# Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I was using mailgun:

`.env` code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox******.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=9******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox********.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-*********
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: hello@yourdomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME: reza
```

Send mail code:

```
$data = array(
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'date' => $time,
            'time' => $request->input('start'),
            'address' => $request->input('title'),
            'end' => $date->modify("+{$duration} minutes"),
        );


Mailgun::send('emails.Meeting', $data, function ($message) {
            $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
        });
```

When call this function, I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'message' of non-object

Why?

Comment: where is `$message` defined in your code?

Comment: I hit this error in  :  vendor\bogardo\mailgun\src\Http\Response.php

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake I think here is

```
$message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
```

Try this

```
       $data = array(
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'date' => $time,
            'time' => $request->input('start'),
            'address' => $request->input('title'),
            'end' => $date->modify("+{$duration} minutes"),
        );


       Mailgun::send('emails.Meeting', $data, function ($message) {
            $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Doe');
            $message->subject('Welcome!');
        });
```

If the above code doesn't work, How's your emails.Meeting template looks like?

Comment: i hit error in line in vendor   

        $this->message = $response->http_response_body->message;

Comment: Looks like that comes from your emails.Meeting template. Are you trying to use $message inside the template by any means? If so do not do that..